# native scroll for android does not work

Tags: android, livecode

I'm trying to create a native Android scroller using the code below. I saved the stack as a standalone app and installed to my Android tablet but the text does not scroll.

```
local sScrollerID

on preOpenCard
   local tScrollerRect, tContentRect

   // Only create a scroller on a mobile device
   if environment() is not "mobile" then exit preOpenCard

   // Set the area of the scroller
  put the rect of group "scrollArea" into tScrollerRect

   // Set the are of the content to be scrolled
   put the left of field "lorem",the top of field "lorem",the right of field "lorem",the formattedHeight of field "lorem" into tContentRect

   // Create the scroller control
   mobileControlCreate "scroller", "loremScroll"
   put the result into sScrollerID

   // Set the properties of the scroller
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "rect", tScrollerRect
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "contentRect", tContentRect
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "visible", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "scrollingEnabled", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "vIndicator", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "vscroll", 0
end preOpenCard

on closeCard
   // Delete the scroller
   if environment() is not "mobile" then exit closeCard
   mobileControlDelete sScrollerID
end closeCard

on scrollerDidScroll hOffset, vOffset
   // When the user scrolls move the displayed content
   set the vScroll of group "scrollArea" to vOffset
end scrollerDidScroll
```

How do I correct the script? The stack is here for anyone who needs to see it: [native scroll in android.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/native%20scroll%20in%20android.zip)

=========

I also tried to create same kind of scrolling for a group consisting of several text fields and even with the suggestions from Mark (see below) it still does notwork.

the code is here:

```
local sScrollerID

on openCard
   local tScrollerRect, tContentRect

   // Only create a scroller on a mobile device
   if environment() is not "mobile" then exit openCard

   // Set the area of the scroller
   put the rect of group "scrollArea" into tScrollerRect

   // Set the area of the content to be scrolled
   put the left of group "scrollArea",the top of group "scrollArea",the formattedWidth of group "scrollArea",the formattedHeight of group "scrollArea" into tContentRect


   // Create the scroller control
   mobileControlCreate "scroller", "loremScroll"
   put the result into sScrollerID

   // Set the properties of the scroller
    mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "rect", tScrollerRect
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "contentRect", tContentRect
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "visible", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "scrollingEnabled", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "vIndicator", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "vscroll", 0
end openCard

on closeCard
   // Delete the scroller
  if environment() is not "mobile" then exit closeCard
   mobileControlDelete sScrollerID
end closeCard

on scrollerDidScroll hOffset, vOffset
   // When the user scrolls move the displayed content
   set the vScroll of group "scrollArea" to vOffset
end scrollerDidScroll
```

What corrections do I have to make for the group scroll to function?
The stack can be downloaded from here: [native scroll in android-group.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/native%20scroll%20in%20android-group.zip)

================

3) Now that the scrolling for the group works properly I attempted to create same scrolling for a data grid using this code:

```
on openCard

      local tScrollerRect, tContentRect

   // Only create a scroller on a mobile device
   if environment() is not "mobile" then exit openCard

   // Set the area of the scroller
   put the rect of group "DataGrid 1" into tScrollerRect

   // Set the area of the content to be scrolled
  put 0,0,(the formattedWidth of group "DataGrid 1"),(the formattedHeight of group "DataGrid 1") into tContentRect

   // Create the scroller control
   mobileControlCreate "scroller", "loremScroll"
   put the result into sScrollerID

   // Set the properties of the scroller
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "rect", tScrollerRect
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "contentRect", tContentRect
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "visible", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "scrollingEnabled", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "vIndicator", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "vscroll", 0

end openCard


on closeCard
   // Delete the scroller
   if environment() is not "mobile" then exit closeCard
   mobileControlDelete sScrollerID
 end closeCard

 on scrollerDidScroll hOffset, vOffset
   // When the user scrolls move the displayed content
   set the vScroll of group "DataGrid 1" to vOffset
 end scrollerDidScroll
```

But the scrolling of the data grid does not work with this code. What corrections do I have to make?
The stack can be downloaded here: [DG-android native scroller.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/DG-android%20native%20scroller.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking the contectRect of a field and then are trying to scroll a group. Probably you want to scroll the field, so you need to change

```
on scrollerDidScroll hOffset, vOffset
   // When the user scrolls move the displayed content
   set the vScroll of group "scrollArea" to vOffset
end scrollerDidScroll
```

into

```
on scrollerDidScroll hOffset, vOffset
   // When the user scrolls move the displayed content
   set the vScroll of fld "lorem" to vOffset
end scrollerDidScroll
```

If you really want to scroll the group, then you need to set tContentRect in the preOpenCard handler to the formattedWidth and formattedHeight of the group.

Comment: I changed to "set the vScroll of fld "lorem" to vOffset" but it did not work. I also tried with changing "put the rect of group "scrollArea" into tScrollerRect" to "put the rect of fld "lorem" into tScrollerRect"and it did not work either. Finally I tried scrolling the group by changing this line: "put the left of group "scrollArea",the top of group "scrollArea",the formattedWidth of group "scrollArea",the formattedHeight of group "scrollArea" into tContentRect" which I'm not sure if it's correct, and it did not work either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It may sound strange, but could you try setting up the scroll view in an openCard handler instead of a preOpenCard handler? In the preOpenCard handler, things haven't rendered yet and I don't know if the rect properties are known to mobileControlSet command already, at that stage. Just to be sure. I'll keep thinking about this.

Comment: Yes, openCard handler was the fix. Thanks! Now I tried to create similar scrolling for a group consisting of several text fields (see above my addition and the code) but again it does not work.

Comment: I found the solution for the group scrolling - this line: put 0,0,(the formattedWidth of group "scrollArea"),(the formattedHeight of group "scrollArea") into tContentRect  under // Set the area of the content to be scrolled instead of: put the left of group "scrollArea",the top of group "scrollArea",the formattedWidth of group "scrollArea",the formattedHeight of group "scrollArea" into tContentRect

Comment: Now probably the most difficult task: how to create the native scroller for a data grid -see the added code above.

Comment: A datagrid is a group. My first take would be to use the formattedHeight of the dataGrid. If that doesn't work, we'd have to find a way to "guess" the total height (or max scroll) of the dataGrid. That's complicated, so I hope that the formattedHeight will work.

Comment: I tried with this line: put 0,0,(the formattedWidth of group "DataGrid 1"),(the formattedHeight of group "DataGrid 1") into tContentRect but it did not work. So how to proceed now?

Comment: I tried with Hanson's suggestion from this lesson: http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4069/l/94412-creating-a-native-scroller-to-scroll-a-field answering Kevin's question. He said: "...make the datagrid as big as you need it to be so you can fit all of the data on one page, that way removing its own scrollers. The result could then be added to a group that is controlled by the native mobile scrollers." I did just that - see attached stack.href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/android%20native%20scroller%20for%20data%20grid2.zip and still the scrolling does not work.

Comment: One more thing when using Hanson's trick. When making the dg so big as to fit 640 text lines without the scroller the height of it is about 16000! Then it takes loooong time to start up such an app. I guess it's because all the lines are being loaded at once, while with the scroller just the visible lines are loaded. (The attached stacks has only 15 lines).

Comment: Hi Keram. I think it is better to start a new question and include the general context together with all the information that is in your last 6 comments. You can post a link to your new question here.

Comment: A datagrid with a height of 16000 will probably not scroll correctly. Moreover, the whole idea of the datagrid is exactly that you don't need such tricks --not even behind the scenes or under the hood.

Comment: I got it fixed thanks to Klaus on the LC Forum. The lines that had to be corrected were: put 0,0,(the DGformattedWidth of group "DataGrid 1"),(the DGformattedHeight of group "DataGrid 1") into tContentRect   and   set the DGvScroll of group "DataGrid 1" to vOffset. It still does not work perfectly so I created a new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943152/native-android-scroller-for-data-grid