# Native Android scroller for Data Grid

Tags: livecode

I'm using the code below for native Adroid scroller for Data Grid and it works almost OK. Almost, because in one particular view in my stack it seems to be unreliable. Download the stack and check the following: Go back and forth 3-4 times clicking between "My Categories" and "My Selection" then at some point the scrolling does not work in the "My Categories" view. I then have to restart the app and it works OK.
What do you think it depends on?
The code is:

```
    on openCard

      local tScrollerRect, tContentRect

   // Only create a scroller on a mobile device
   if environment() is not "mobile" then exit openCard

   // Set the area of the scroller
   put the rect of group "DataGrid 1" into tScrollerRect

   // Set the area of the content to be scrolled
  put 0,0,(the DGformattedWidth of group "DataGrid 1"),(the DGformattedHeight of group "DataGrid 1") into tContentRect

   // Create the scroller control
   mobileControlCreate "scroller", "loremScroll"
   put the result into sScrollerID

   // Set the properties of the scroller
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "rect", tScrollerRect
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "contentRect", tContentRect
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "visible", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "scrollingEnabled", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "vIndicator", true
   mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "vscroll", 0

end openCard


on closeCard
   // Delete the scroller
   if environment() is not "mobile" then exit closeCard
   mobileControlDelete sScrollerID
 end closeCard

on scrollerDidScroll hOffset, vOffset
   // When the user scrolls move the displayed content
   set the DGvScroll of group "DataGrid 1" to vOffset
end scrollerDidScroll
```

You can download the stack [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/android%20native%20scroller%20for%20data%20grid4.zip).

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and installed your stack. If I just scroll, all seems to work fine. If I click on My Categories, it doesn't scroll, probably because the contentRect is incorrect. If I click on My Selection, the datagrid is empty and obviously scrolling won't work.

I suggest you execute

```
put 0,0,(the DGformattedWidth of group "DataGrid 1"),(the DGformattedHeight of group "DataGrid 1") into tContentRect
mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "contentRect", tContentRect
```

every time when the script of one of the buttons All Categories, My Selection or My Categories runs.

Comment: With correction in all the buttons All Categories, My Selection or My Categories scripts it is even worse - the correct groups are not put into grid. When I disable line:
mobileControlSet "loremScroll", "contentRect", tContentRect
then it woks better. Still the scrolling in the My Selection or My Categories does not work properly. When resstart the app then the scrolling works OK. "If I click on My Selection, the datagrid is empty and obviously scrolling won't work." That's correct, you have to make few selections first, enough in numbers to exceed the height of the dg.

Comment: The corrected stack is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/android%20native%20scroller%20for%20data%20grid_correction1.zip

Comment: I've got it working OK. It is still very slow when scrolling in my main app but in this 1-page sample is OK. Link is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/android%20native%20scroller%20for%20data%20grid_correction2.zip